# How to use advance mysql query in Pyramid framework

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Now, I'm thinking about to change pyramid from PHP. I'm using advance
sql query for searching

Current mysql is using

```
SELECT * , IF( `Word` = 'sim', 1, IF( `Word` LIKE 'sim%', 2,
IF( `Word` LIKE '%sim', 4, 3 ) ) ) AS `sort` FROM `dblist` WHERE
`Word` LIKE '%sim%' ORDER BY `sort` , `Word`;
```

When I read pyramid, there is no code to run sql. Pyramid is using
SQLAlchemy. I am not familier with ORM. Can ORM run sql ? How to run
above query in pyramid ? My current database is using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your claim is wrong!

Pyramid has no concept of backend storage and is open to *every possible* backend storage.
There are add-ons supporting a RDBMS-based persistence e.g. through SQLAlchemy.

e.g. there is

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/khufu_sqlalchemy/0.5.1

for integration of SQLAlchemy with Pyramid

In general:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid.html

or also: follow the pylons-discuss mailing list.

Comment: thank. I just start reading pyramid from http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/. I didn't find example for sql. Thank. Now, I'm reading khufu sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2):

See the SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch Wiki Tutorial for an example how to use SQLAlchemy with Pyramid: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/tutorials/wiki2/index.html